# apache cordova show local img file

Tags: android, cordova

I have image paths stored in my websql database. 
Paths like:

```
/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150212_21212.jpg
```

I want to display these images within my image element:

```
<img src="path" />
```

But the image is not displayed. I know that path is wrong, so I tried these variations:

```
file:///storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150212_21212.jpg
cdvfile://storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150212_21212.jpg
file://localhost/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150212_21212.jpg
cdvfile://localhost/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150212_21212.jpg
```

What is the correct path and how can I display the image?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on android:

"file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150212_21212.jpg"

Comment: don' works form me :(
I tried these variations:
file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150212_21212.jpg
file:///mnt/storage/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150212_21212.jpg

Comment: I tried these variation too:

file:///sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20150212_21212.jpg